# error creating mapping { Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [string] declared on field [category]

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, frontend, backend

I am not able to solve the issue here. I have tried creating the mapping so that my code can be compatible with ES6x but still not able to figure out the problem. There might be some problem with my code but I couldn't pinpoint the exact issue.

Here, is my index.js code

```
Product.createMapping(
    {

           "products": {
               "properties": {
                   "category": {
                       "type": "keyword"
                   },
                   "name": {
                       "type": "text"
                   },
                   "price": {
                       "type": "double"
                   },
                   "image": {
                       "type": "text"
                   }
               }
           }


    }, function(err, mapping){
    if (err) {
        console.log('error creating mapping');
        console.log(err);
    }

    else{
        console.log('Mapping successfully created');
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});

var data = Product.synchronize();
var count = 0;

data.on('date', function(){
    count++;
});

data.on('close', function(){
    console.log('Indexed' + count + 'Documents');
});

data.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Here is my product.js code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'},
    image: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

schema.plugin(mongoosastic,{
    hosts: [
        'localhost:9200'
    ]
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

Comment: Your code says `"category": { "type": "keyword"}` while error says **type [string] declared on field [category]**. Are you sure this code is generating the error?

Comment: @NishantSaini Yes, this code is generating the error but I am not able to figure out the issue. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try making direct call to elastic using postman to create the index. I don't see any issue in that mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare es_type in your schema declaration like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' ,es_type:'keyword'},
image: {type: String, required: true ,es_type:'text'},
name: {type: String, required: true ,,es_type:'text'},
price: {type: Number, required: true ,,es_type:'double'}
});
```